# Create a toggle close button

Tags: php, javascript, toggle

can i remove the fancy from the below script and create an event of toggle with close button on it. this a script i am using on my website in listings, so wanna create a toggle for for multiple id's

```
$("a.fmailto").click(function(event){

var nr = jQuery(this).attr("id").substr(6);
var arr = nr.split("_");
var user_id = arr[0];
var listing_id = arr[1];
$.fancybox({
    'width' : 630,
    'height' : 600,
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'margin' : '0',
    'padding' : '0',
    'titleShow' : false,
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'href' : '{/literal}{$live_site}{literal}/mailto.php?id='+user_id+'&amp;ad_id='+listing_id
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>toggle me</div>
<a onclick="$('div').toggle();"></a>
```

or literaly:

```
$(function(){
$('a').on('click',function(){
$('div').toggle();

});

});
```